# How to define a unique index for an element of an arrary in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to define a unique index for the last element of an array? is that even possible in mongo?

only `status[this.status.length-1].state` and `user_id` for `specific status.state` (e.g active) has to be unique.

note: the last element of status array define the user's current status.

e.g: 2 user_id with `status[this.status.length-1].state: **revoked**` state can be exist. but 2 user_id with `status[this.status.length-1].state: **active**` cannot be exist.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a609778c6929e7122322cf"),
    "user_id": '9e2cZ'
    "status" : [ 
        {
            "state" : "active",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-30T21:23:21.158Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-30T21:23:21.158Z")
        }, 
        {
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:24:02.613Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:24:02.613Z"),
            "state" : "revoked"
        }, 
        {
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:25:02.888Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:25:02.888Z"),
            "state" : "active"
        }
    ],

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Index an array element

The only way that I know to perform it is to reverse your problem.
The latest status should be in first position of your array.
You can insert it with [unshift function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp). And create your index this way :

```
db.coll.createIndex({user_id:1, 'status.0.state': 1})
```

This will index the **first** element of your array.

Here is the explain that show the use of the index :

```
db.coll.find({user_id: 1, 'status.0.state': "active"}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan
{
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                        "user_id" : 1,
                        "status.0.state" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "user_id_1_status.0.state_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "user_id" : [ ],
                        "status.0.state" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                        "user_id" : [
                                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                        ],
                        "status.0.state" : [
                                "[\"active\", \"active\"]"
                        ]
                }
        }
}
```

To insert your status in node you should turn

```
user.status.push(newStatus);
```

into

```
user.status.unshift(newStatus);
```

### Unique index with partial indexes

To have a uniqueness on the active status, you can combine the previous answer with a partial index.
The partial index will index **only** the active users.

Here is the index creation command :

```
db.users.createIndex(
  {user_id:1, 'status.0.state': 1}, 
  {unique: true, partialFilterExpression: {"status.0.state": {$eq: 'active'}}}
)
```

Then, I insert 2 users, one active and one inactive

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a609778c6929e7122322cd"),
    "user_id" : "9e2cZ",
    "status" : [
        {
            "state" : "inactive",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-30T21:23:21.158Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-30T21:23:21.158Z")
        },
        {
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:24:02.613Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:24:02.613Z"),
            "state" : "revoked"
        },
        {
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:25:02.888Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:25:02.888Z"),
            "state" : "active"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a609778c6929e7122322cf"),
    "user_id" : "9e2cZ",
    "status" : [
        {
            "state" : "active",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-30T21:23:21.158Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-30T21:23:21.158Z")
        },
        {
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:24:02.613Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:24:02.613Z"),
            "state" : "revoked"
        },
        {
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:25:02.888Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-31T22:25:02.888Z"),
            "state" : "active"
        }
    ]
}
```

It works, I have 2 users with the same user_id but different statuses.

If I try to insert another active user with the same user_id, it fails :

```
> db.users.insert({user_id: '9e2cZ', status: [{state: 'active'}]})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: user_id_1_status.0.state_1 dup key: { : \"9e2cZ\", : \"active\" }"
    }
})
```

This way, you have an unique index based on the first element of an array.

Comment: Really great suggestion!! I think I'll run into another issue with mongo's index unique, the index uniqueness needs to be on `active` only. We may have multiple revoked status for the same user_id but cannot have multiple active status, meaning the uniqueness has to be applied only on last/first element of an array with active status only. I think I have to enforce the uniqueness programmatically. any thoughts?

Comment: I will post an exemple for it with partial index in the same answer

Comment: You saved my time a ton. Wish I could up-vote your answer again :) Thank You